# cannot insert java.sql.Date to the "Date" field in the database

Tags: java, sql

I am getting a string value such as "2012-01-20" and converting it to sql.Date to insert it in the database.

code

```
java.util.Date DOB = new java.util.Date();
String datetext = txtDate.getText();

SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
DOB = sd.parse(datetext);
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(DOB.getTime());

String query = "ISERT INTO EMPLOYEE ('DOB')"
                   + " VALUES ( ? ) ";

con = db.createConnection();
 try{
     ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
     ps.setDate(1, sqlDate);
     ps.executeQuery();
    }catch(Exception ex){
       System.err.print(ex);
  }
```

When i run this code I am getting an exception ""[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Optional feature not implemented"

what am i doing wrong here ? pls help !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove single quote -  ('DOB') and `INSERT` (misspell)

```
String query = "INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (DOB) VALUES (?)";
```

You may use `java.sql.Date.valueOf("2012-01-20")` method to convert string to sql date.

Use `executeUpdate()` method instead of executeQuery().

```
String query = "INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (DOB) VALUES (?)";

con = db.createConnection();
 try{
     ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
     ps.setDate(1, java.sql.Date.valueOf("2012-01-20"));
     //Or use
     //  ps.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(DOB.getTime())); 
     ps.executeUpdate();
    }catch(Exception ex){
       System.err.print(ex);
  }
```

Comment: the "valueof" method is not found ? why is that

Comment: Date.valueOf() - More info - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html

Comment: Thanks , I corrected that. But making all the modifications as You suggested , still does not solve the problem. It gives the same exception.

Comment: @ReezaMuaz - May be you missed something to set ODBC DSN. See I've edited post.

Comment: the DSN is already set and connection is made successfully. When I am debugging the executeUpdate() line is not even reached, after the ps.setDate() it throws the exception. :/

Comment: What is field type of DOB? How many columns are there in a table?

Comment: the field type is "Date" and there are 6 columns actually, the actual query looks like this "INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (DOB,FIRST_NAME,MIDDLE_NAME,LAST_NAME,SALARY,ADDRESS) VALUES ( ?,?,?,?,?,?) ";

Comment: May be try to call setTimestamp instead of setDate. ps.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(DOB.getTime()));